# Firebase Facebook autentificación lógica (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, oauth2

Os planteo un problema de lógica que tengo actualmente en mi aplicación.

El primer apartado de mi aplicación (en Android) es Iniciar sesión, en el cual tengo el típico login para iniciar con email y contraseña, y el botón de facebook. 
Además de esto, tengo un apartado de registrar, en el que te pide unos datos para el usuario en varios apartados, y en el último te pide ingresar el email y password, para aceptarlo y ya lanzar la aplicación con el usuario iniciado.

Internamente, necesito todos estos datos, porque cuando registro con email y contraseña, inserto en Firebase los campos necesarios para que la aplicación funcione, en la tabla "Usuarios" y así...

Pero mi duda es la siguiente, el botón de Facebook sirve tanto para registrar como para iniciar sesión, y yo tengo puesto uno en la primera pantalla de inicio sesión y en la última del registro, por si no quieres meter el email, pero, si la primera vez que abro la aplicación, pulso en "Iniciar sesión con Facebook" el apartado de Registro no se lanza, con lo cual no se inserta nada en Firebase y la aplicación simplemente no funciona.

¿Qué puedo hacer para remediar esto? ¿Hay alguna manera de que haya un botón de Facebook para iniciar y otro para registrar?

Comment: Hola Traif,
Sin código es muy difícil diagnosticar el problema. Si estás usando el login de Facebook a través de Firebase al hacer el login el usuario este queda registrado en el listado de Firebase y deberías poder verlo en la consola. No hay un registro. Estas usando el SDK de facebook directamente o a traves de Firebase? una vez que pase la instancia de login puedes chequear si ese usuario tiene los datos de registro cargados y en caso negativo enviarlos a la pantalla de registro.

Comment: Has seguido toda la documentación de Facebook y Firebase?  ,  algunas veces por la configuración el popup simplemente no se lanza. Seria bueno dar mas detalles, por ejemplo el código de la app donde está el problema.

Comment: Al final lo he realizado como comenta el usuario jirungaray, me parecia la solución más rapida de realizarlo. Muchas gracias!